# The convergence of $ \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}x=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f$ be continuous such that $$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(f\left(x+1\right)-f\left(x\right)\right)=0$$ show that $$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x}\right)=0$$

My idea was applying the sequential criterion for continuity: that if $f$ is continuous at $c$ if and only if for every sequence $x_n$ that converges to $c$, $f(x)$ converges to $f(c)$.  Also, I have the idea that since $$\lim_{x\to \infty }\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(f\left(x+1\right)\right),$$ I can use it somehow in the demonstration, or am I wrong?

Comment: The last two limits you've written might not exist, so you cannot use something like that.

Comment: If we had instead $f(x+1)-f(x)=0,$ then $f$ would be periodic with period $1$ and the theorem would be easy to prove.  So I would start by proving that that, and then trying to modify the proof to cover the given situation.  Just a suggestion -- I haven't tried it.

Comment: Assume that $f(x)/x$ does not approach $0$ and see if you find this assumption contradicts the hypothesis.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2119937/limit-of-ratio-fx-over-x-equal-to-limit-of-difference-fx1-fx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @ConnorHarris In the question you pointed to the function $f$ is supposed bounded.

Comment: @egreg Bounded on finite open intervals, not on all of $\mathbb{R}$.